# Canon LP-E6NH battery moisture

Tags: canon, battery

i recently purchased a brand new Eos R with the included LP-E6nh battery. After hours of shooting i charge my battery, when its done charging i see some liquid on the ports/terminal of the battery, and i wipe it off. i didn't use it for a while because im afraid it may cause some harm to my camera. Now i try to use it again all seems good and take a couple of shots with the battery, then i take it off from the camera and i can see a small liquid again on the battery, can someone explain whats happening with the battery? Thank you.

Comment: Definitely try to get the battery replaced under warranty.Don't use it any longer or it could damage the camera.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no liquid in a lithium battery... and if liquid does come in contact with lithium things can go very bad very quickly.

I would put that battery inside a metal container and get it replaced; based on your description I would consider it hazardous and a fire risk.